# SSRS truncating image

Tags: image, reporting-services, background

I am working on a landscape report using VS 2012 SQL Server Data Tools and keep hitting a roadblock with an embedded background image.  The image is the same size as the report (11 x 8.5).  When I import the image and set the background image to embedded the image truncates and repeats.  I confirmed this is definitely happening when I increased the size of the image and imported and it worked. Unfortunately, this isn't a great solution because when I resize the image there is a degradation in quality.  Is there a setting I'm missing?  I've tried both jpg and png and have the same issue with the truncation.

NOTE:  This is happening before I even get to the point where I deploy on the server.  As a test, I tried going with the background as is and deploying but it's still truncated.

Comment: It sounds like the size of your image file is too big. I think there is a limit to the size of embedded pics and it is truncating the pic when it embeds it in the report. Unfortunately, MSDN seems to be re-worked with useful information removed. I think there was a 4 meg limit. Can you resize your image in a decent pic editor so the filesize is smaller and see it that helps?

Comment: Wish that was it, but these files are under 1 MB.